# How to show body of a bad request response in angular 4?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

To provide login error message I added a message in the constructor of Bad Request Response which shows in the postman while testing an web api.
Like this: return BadRequest("Error Message");
Now I want to get that message and display in a component in the client side. But I don't know how to retrieve that. I am trying like this:

```
signIn() {
this.authService.login(this.loginCredentials).subscribe(result=>{
  if(result){
    let returnUrl=this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl');
    this.router.navigate([returnUrl||'/']);
  } 
},
(err) => {
  this.loginMessage=true;
  console.log(err.body);
  this.invalidLogin=true;
});
```

}

Comment: It may be in `err.error.body`, but definitely it will be useful to see the full response object from network tab in your browser, if you could copy that json and update your question, that will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Comment: @RobinKhan Maybe, you should give the credit to Maksym. Let him post the comment as an answer and mark it as an answer.

Comment: okay, I have no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it. It will be

```
console.log(err.body);
```